# html input boxes taken in one row but second textbox not apearing in same row

Tags: html, asp.net

Here is my code which written in ASP.Net web page where i am adding three html textboxes in one row but third text box is not coming in  same row or line.

```
<div class="row">
                        <div class="col-4 pt-3" style="margin-left: 50px;">
                            <div class="input-group" style="width: 200px;">
                                <input type="text" runat="server" id="NameTextBox" class="form-control merch-name" placeholder="Merchant Description" aria-label="Description" maxlength="25" tabindex="6" />
                            </div>
                            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="NameHdn" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4 pt-3" style="margin-left: 50px;">
                            <div class="input-group" style="width: 150px;">
                                <input type="text" runat="server" id="TransactionAmountTextBox" class="form-control currency-input" placeholder="From " aria-label="From Transaction Amount" data-allownegative="true" style="width: 100px;" maxlength="14" tabindex="7" onkeyup="sync()"/>                                                         
                                 <%-- <input type="text" runat="server" id="AmountTextBox"  maxlength="14" tabindex="13"/> 
                                  <input type="text" runat="server" id="Text1"  maxlength="14" tabindex="13" onkeyup="sync()"/> --%>
                            </div>
                            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="AmountHdn" ClientIDMode="Static" />                            
                        </div>
                        <%--Added Comaprison Dollar Search --%>
                        <div class="col-4 pt-3" style="margin-left: 150px;">
                            <div class="input-group" style="width: 150px;">
                                 <%--<input type="text" runat="server" id="AmountTextBox_2"  maxlength="14" tabindex="13" />  --%>
                                <%--<input type="text" runat="server" id="Text2"  maxlength="14" tabindex="13" onkeyup="sync()"/>--%>
                                <input type="text" runat="server" id="AmountTextBox_2" class="form-control currency-input" placeholder="To " aria-label="To Transaction Amount" data-allownegative="true" style="width: 100px;" maxlength="14" tabindex="13" />  
                            </div>
                            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="ToAmountHdn" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

[image: Err Image]

[image: After removing margin-left output]

Comment: `margin-left`  in every `div.col-4` causing the third `input` to came down. So remove it

Comment: we would need to see your CSS to be sure, but there's maybe just not enough place in the container to display all 3 of them. I'm also not sure what you're trying to achieve, but using `<br>` in between div's (or at all, for what it's worth) is not a good idea...

Comment: @ShashankGb - Actually i tried to remove margin-left , then it came in line but bcoz of one more column little bit overlapping is there.i am attaching snapshot in qns.

Comment: @LaurentS. <br> was only for test purpose i kept that , just now i modified my code and removed <br>

Comment: remove _style="margin-left: 50px;"_ from every div column

Comment: @vim can you provide full code (Transcation col code).

Comment: @LaurentS. i think you are correct , space is the problem.i took another row for these two textboxes and its looks better..but my initial requirement was to fix it in same row all three.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to extra margin you are giving to columns. Remote style tag margin from column.

Switch

```
class="col-4 pt-3" style="margin-left: 50px;"
```

To

```
class="col-4 pt-3"
```